# RewriteCond QUERY_STRING or/and ProxyPass?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, proxypass

I have to forward requests from internet client like this one :

https://www.app.com/AppServer?User=guest&ID=8PKX3Q2DT45&Type=laptop&Cmd=exec

to internal server with changing some parameters :

https://192.168.0.1/AppServer?User=guest&ID=NEW_ID&Type=NEW_TYPE&Cmd=exec

with Apache web server. NEW_ID and NEW_TYPE are static variables.

I've tried differents things with ProxyPass and RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} but without success.

```
RewriteEngine On
```

`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .*User=(\w+).*&ID=(\w+).*&Type=(\w+).*&Cmd=(\w+).*$ [NC]
 RewriteRule . HOST/AppServer?User=$1&ID=NEW_ID&Type=NEW_TYPE&Cmd=Exec [R=301,L]`

```
ProxyPass HOST/AppServer
ProxyPassReverse HOST/AppServer
```

(URL has been replaced with HOST because of post restriction)

Also, I should be able to change header with RequestHeader (this work properly).

Could you help me to build the configuration ?

Kindest regards,

Answer (score 0):

I answer to my question, this work :

```
#NEW UA
RequestHeader set User-Agent "NEW_UA"

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)OLD_ID(.*)OLD_DEVICE(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) HOST/AppServer/?%1NEW_ID%2NEW_DEVICE%3 [P,L]

ProxyPass / HOST/
ProxyPassReverse / HOST
```

Thanks,